# setState won't work in handleClick

Tags: reactjs, setstate

my setState doesn't chance the state in the handleClick event handler. 
I'm sure the handleClick works because it logs the param.
I'm kind of new to React so I must be overlooking something.
Does this mean there is something wrong with my handleClick function?

Any advice would be really appreciated!

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './Projects.css';
    import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer.js';
    import ProjectPage from 
      '../../Components/ProjectPage/ProjectPage.js';
    import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

    class Projects extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state= {
          title: "kaufmann house",
          content: "charles",
        }
        this.getImages = this.getImages.bind(this);
      }

      getImages() {
        var VisibilitySensor = require('react-visibility-sensor');
        return this.props.projectList.map((post,index) =>
       <div>
          <div className="projects">
            <VisibilitySensor onChange={isVisible => 
              this._onChange(isVisible, post.title)}>
              <img key={post.id} src={post.featureImage} 
                className='projectImage' alt='projectImage' onClick= . 
                {this.handleClick.bind(this, post.content)}/>
            </VisibilitySensor>
          </div>
        </div>
        )
      }

      _onChange = (isVisible, param) => {
        isVisible && this.setState({title: param});
      };

      handleClick = (param) => {
        console.log(param);
        this.setState({content: param});
      };

      render() {

        return (
           <div>
            <Link to={{pathname: `/ProjectPage/${this.state.title}`,
                state: {
                  info: `${this.state.content}`}
                }}>{this.getImages()}</Link>
            <Link to={{pathname: `/ProjectPage/${this.state.title}`,
                state: {
                  info: `${this.state.content}`}
                }}>
              <Footer title={this.state.title}/>
             </Link>
          </div>
        )
       }
    }



    export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   this.state= {
      title: "kaufmann house",
      content: "charles",
    }
```

Your `state` contains title and content. You have to `setState` like below. Otherwise, your new `state` will not update correctly because you replaced the whole `state` object.

```
  _onChange = (isVisible, param) => {
    isVisible && this.setState({
       ...this.state,
       title: param
     });
  };

  handleClick = (param) => {
    console.log(param);
    this.setState({ 
       ...this.state,
       content: param
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following changes:

1) Move var VisibilitySensor = require('react-visibility-sensor');
to the top of your file to keep your component clean

```
import React from 'react';
import './Projects.css';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer.js';
import ProjectPage from 
      '../../Components/ProjectPage/ProjectPage.js';
import { Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import VisibilitySensor from 'react-visibility-sensor';
```

2) Regarding your click handler, it is a bad practice to create handler functions using bind, because this may cause a performance issue since a new function will be created on each render. you can use an arrow function and set data-[attribute]
to add data to your component

```
getImages() {
  //var VisibilitySensor = require('react-visibility-sensor'); remove this line
  return this.props.projectList.map((post,index) => (
     <div key={post.id}>
       <div className="projects">
         <VisibilitySensor onChange={isVisible => 
          this._onChange(isVisible, post.title)}>
           <img src={post.featureImage}
              data-content={post.content}
              className='projectImage' 
              alt='projectImage' 
              onClick={this.handleClick}/>
         </VisibilitySensor>
       </div>
     </div>
  ))
}


handleClick = (e) => {
    var content = e.target.dataset.content;
    this.setState((state) => ({
       ...state,
       content
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @AngelSalazar for pointing out better ways to structure my code. I made the changes you suggested.  Only the problem is still there.  The setState in the handleClick arrow function doesn't update the state.  But whenever I log the content in the handleClick function, it logs the post.content data.  Any idea what might be the problem?